# If $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$ and $g$ is not identically zero, then $g(0)= 1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

(i) for all $y_{1},y_{2} \in (0, \infty)$, $g(y_{1}+y_{2})=g(y_{1})(y_{2})$

Suppose in addition that

(ii) there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(y)\neq 0$

Prove that $g(0)=1$

---

I am supposed to use both conditions, however this is the only way I can figure out how to do it.  Could anybody tell me if I am doing it correctly or in what step I am using the second condition?

Since $0 = 0 + 0$ we have $g(0)=g(0 + 0)$.  By condition (i) we have $g(0+0)=g(0)g(0)$. So $g(0)=g(0)g(0)$. Then dividing both sides by $g(0)$, we have $g(0)=1$.

That seems to prove it, but I did not use the second condition.  At least I don't think I did? Am I wrong?

Comment: $g(0)=g(0)g(0)\implies g(0)=1$ or $g(0)=0.$

Comment: Now you just have to discard the second case presented by @mfl... Can you use the second conditions?

Comment: For suitable $y$, you have $0\ne g(y)=g(y+0)=g(y)g(0)$, so ... ?

Comment: Do you only have those conditions in $(0,\infty)$, not $[0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $g(y)=g(0+y)=g(0)g(y)$, where $g(y)\not=0$, then $g(y)(1-g(0))=0 \implies g(0)=1.$